# error: expression is not assignable ternary operator

Tags: c, struct, unions, ternary

I have the following code and MPLABX XC8 compiler gives this error:

> error: expression is not assignable
>
> ```
> U1ERRIRbits.RXFOIF ? uart1.oerr = 1 : uart1.oerr = 0;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
> ```

Here is the relevant code section:

```
typedef union {
    struct {
        bool ferr  : 1;  // FERIF Framing Error
        bool aerr  : 1;  // ABDOVF Error
        bool oerr  : 1;  // RXFOIF Error
        bool ready : 1;  // Data Ready to be read
        uint8_t reserved : 4;
    };
    uint8_t status;
}uart1_status_t;

static volatile uart1_status_t uart1;
```

> `U1ERRIRbits.RXFOIF ? uart1.oerr = 1 : uart1.oerr = 0;`

Same thing does not give error when I use

```
if (U1ERRIRbits.RXFOIF) 
    uart1.oerr = 1;
else 
    uart1.oerr = 0;
```

Do not understand why?

Comment: How about `uart1.oerr = U1ERRIRbits.RXFOIF? 1:0;` instead?

Comment: Try instead `U1ERRIRbits.RXFOIF ? uart1.oerr = 1 : (uart1.oerr = 0)`. Condition binds stronger than assignment. [C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: @Blaze thank you! It looks way better
@ Scheff thank you for the answer! :)

Comment: What does this mean? "Same thing does not give error when I use" This is not the same thing at all! A ternary operator is (as any operator) used as part of an expression. Expressions do not create lvalues. In your alternate version you have separate statements where you assign a value to an lvalue.

Comment: General rule: A ternary operator is not the same as an `if` clause

Comment: Another general rule: avoid using `?:` until it is actually needed. Which isn't very often at all.

Answer (score 4):

```
U1ERRIRbits.RXFOIF ? uart1.oerr = 1 : uart1.oerr = 0;
```

is interpreted as:

```
(U1ERRIRbits.RXFOIF ? uart1.oerr = 1 : uart1.oerr) = 0;
```

Which tries to assign `0` to ...? If you want to use such construct, you need braces:

```
U1ERRIRbits.RXFOIF ? uart1.oerr = 1 : (uart1.oerr = 0);
```

Or better:

```
uart1.oerr = U1ERRIRbits.RXFOIF ? 1 : 0;
```

or:

```
uart1.oerr = !!U1ERRIRbits.RXFOIF;
```

or:

```
uart1.oerr = (bool)U1ERRIRbits.RXFOIF;
```

or really just:

```
uart1.oerr = U1ERRIRbits.RXFOIF;
```

as `typeof(uart1.oerr) == bool`, the value will be implicitly converted to `1` for nonzero values or `0` for zero.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple that, due to [C operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence),

```
U1ERRIRbits.RXFOIF ? uart1.oerr = 1 : uart1.oerr = 0;
```

is compiled as

```
(U1ERRIRbits.RXFOIF ? uart1.oerr = 1 : uart1.oerr) = 0;
```

In C, a condition doesn't provide an LValue. Hence, this is a compiler error.

One solution would be to use parentheses:

```
U1ERRIRbits.RXFOIF ? uart1.oerr = 1 : (uart1.oerr = 0);
```

Please note, that `uart1.oerr = 1` doesn't need parentheses as `?` and `:` act like parentheses (a specialty of the ternary operator).

The even simpler solutions are already mentioned in [Kamils answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55377793/7478597)...